# SSIS Package not running from code

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, ssis, dtexec

I am attempting to run an SSIS package from a website using the following code:

```
Process process = new Process();
        try
        {
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

            process.StartInfo.FileName = "dtexec";

            process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/F " + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SSISLocation"] + packageName + " /ConF \"" + configLocation + "\"";

            System.IO.File.AppendAllText(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SSISLocation"] + "Log.txt", "/F " + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SSISLocation"] + packageName + " /ConF \"" + configLocation + "\"\r\n");

            process.Start();
            System.IO.File.AppendAllText(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SSISLocation"] + "Log.txt", process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd() + "\r\n");                                
            process.WaitForExit();

            return true;
        }
```

This fails and my log returns:
Could not create DTS.Application because of error 0x800401F3

I have googled this but there is not much help so I ran the package via command line which works. So I figure it must be permissions so I run psexec to get me a command window under the network service user that the website is running under. it still works but still doesn't work through my website.

I'm not running 64 bit and the machine itself is 32 bit so it wouldn't work on command line even if I were.

The folders being accessed have full permissions to "Everybody"

I am running sql server 2005.

I am running windows server 2003

I have set delay validation all on components that I can without causing issues.

I have run process monitor for both methods and the call looks pretty much the same but here they are anyway:

Via Command line:

Parent PID: 4292, Command line: dtexec /F c:\SSIS\packagename.dtsx /ConF "c:\SSIS\1cee35d1-b181-4ee7-a1de-eb9fc9c5ebe7.dtsConfig", Current directory: C:\WINDOWS\system32, Environment: 
    =C:=C:\WINDOWS\system32
    =ExitCode=00000000
    ALLUSERSPROFILE=C:\Documents and Settings\All Users
    ClusterLog=C:\WINDOWS\Cluster\cluster.log
    CommonProgramFiles=C:\Program Files\Common Files
    COMPUTERNAME=servername
    ComSpec=C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
    FP_NO_HOST_CHECK=NO
    lib=C:\Program Files\SQLXML 4.0\bin\
    NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS=2
    OS=Windows_NT
    Path=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\Dell\SysMgt\oma\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\80\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\
    PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.VBS;.PSC1
    PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=x86
    PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=x86 Family 6 Model 37 Stepping 1, GenuineIntel
    PROCESSOR_LEVEL=6
    PROCESSOR_REVISION=2501
    ProgramFiles=C:\Program Files
    PROMPT=$P$G
    PSModulePath=C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\
    SystemDrive=C:
    SystemRoot=C:\WINDOWS
    TEMP=C:\DOCUME~1\NETWOR~1\LOCALS~1\Temp
    TMP=C:\DOCUME~1\NETWOR~1\LOCALS~1\Temp
    USERDOMAIN=NT AUTHORITY
    USERNAME=NETWORK SERVICE
    USERPROFILE=C:\Documents and Settings\NetworkService
    windir=C:\WINDOWS

Via Website:

Parent PID: 3692, Command line: "dtexec" /F c:\SSIS\RNReport.dtsx /ConF "c:\SSIS\1cee35d1-b181-4ee7-a1de-eb9fc9c5ebe7.dtsConfig", Current directory: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv, Environment: 
    ALLUSERSPROFILE=C:\Documents and Settings\All Users
    APP_POOL_ID=AppPoolName
    ClusterLog=C:\WINDOWS\Cluster\cluster.log
    CommonProgramFiles=C:\Program Files\Common Files
    COMPUTERNAME=servername
    ComSpec=C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
    FP_NO_HOST_CHECK=NO
    lib=C:\Program Files\SQLXML 4.0\bin\
    NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS=2
    OS=Windows_NT
    Path=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\Dell\SysMgt\oma\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\80\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\
    PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.VBS;.PSC1
    PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=x86
    PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=x86 Family 6 Model 37 Stepping 1, GenuineIntel
    PROCESSOR_LEVEL=6
    PROCESSOR_REVISION=2501
    ProgramFiles=C:\Program Files
    PSModulePath=C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\
    SystemDrive=C:
    SystemRoot=C:\WINDOWS
    TEMP=C:\WINDOWS\TEMP
    TMP=C:\WINDOWS\TEMP
    USERPROFILE=C:\Documents and Settings\Default User
    windir=C:\WINDOWS

Any help at all will be most appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: This may be helpful https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/5569bced-c1ae-49cd-9f12-0aa1dd4aad75/could-not-create-dtsapplication-because-of-error-0x800401f3?forum=sqlintegrationservices

Comment: Thanks for the response I have already seen this post but the package runs successfully on the server under command line so everything must be registered and I am running it using the same user exactly. Thank you very much for your response though it's a very specific question.

Comment: Do you run it unattended ? Can you try starting the process for example in c:\ssis instead of c:\windows\system32

Comment: I should be able to run it in that folder yes let me give that a try and get back to you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to run same SSIS package from console application and if it works then try to run same in website. If it runs in console and not in website. Then check where you hosted your website. For example if you hosted your website in IIS, there may be permission privileges to execute ManagedDTS.dll in IIS.

To solve this problem, i had to run console application from website and the console application in turn runs my SSIS package. This is just suggestion and keep try. According to you if the package runs via command line successfully but not via code then the culprit is ManagedDTS.dll.